# chef provision command fails because of missing node name

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

I am trying to use "chef provision", which is part of the ChefDK. I have been trying to follow this article but I encounter an error when running the "chef provision" command.

http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2015/05/15/quick-tip-chefdk-provision/

What am I missing?
Any pointers are much appreciated!

```
$ chef provision testing --sync -n mymachinename
Uploading policy to policy group testing
Error: Failed to upload policy to policy group testing
Reason: (ArgumentError) Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned
```

Comment: What's in your `knife.rb`? I think you haven't configured your workstation, yet. Do commands like `knife client list` work?

Comment: @StephenKing you are correct. This repository had the knife.rb entirely missing. This problem was resolved by having the appropriate knife.rb file in place. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of the message

> Reason: (ArgumentError) Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned

is that you have not yet configured the connection to your Chef Server. Check that there is a [knife.rb](http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) at one of the expected locations and that it defines a `node_name`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I have a knife.rb at c:/users/<username>/.chef/knife.rb with node_name assigned. Any idea?

Comment: Post a separate question.

Comment: Yean, `name` is assigned in my `client.rb` to no avail too.